# Vue.js recursive component's data including props

Tags: vue.js, recursion, vue-component, vue-props

I'm using recursive components in vue.js. Every component has an array where one value is passed from the parent component as a prop. How do I have to create the array to properly include the value/prop?

Here are the details with simplified (untested) code to show the theoretical problem (I know that this example causes infinite recursion :-):

My-component.vue

```
<template>
  {{my_array}}
  <my-component :my_counter="my_array.counter">
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  props: ['my_counter'],
  name: 'my-component', 
  data: function () {
    return {
      new_counter: this.my_counter+1,
      my_array: [name: "static name", counter: this.new_counter]
    }
  },
 }
</script>
```

Though new_counter is properly passed as my_counter prop to the child component, the my_array.counter is not properly updated with the new value.

When I pass new_counter as my_counter property directly (without using the array). It works.

I guess I need to use some kind of reactive data. However, I couldn't find a solution with computed properties, methods etc... How can I make my_array updated by the the passed prop?

What is your recommendation to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that my_array initialized once used props but then it's not updated.
You have to add a watcher like that:

```
watch: {
  my_counter(value) {
    this.my_array = {
      ...this.my_array,
      counter: value
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to Vue.js and I've had similar issues with it and Nuxt.js.
Although, I've got one example that might help you.
Did you try anything like this?

```
<template>
  {{my_array}}
  <my-component :my_counter="compA()">
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  props: ['my_counter'],
  name: 'my-component', 
  computed: {
    compA() {
       const my_counter = this.my_counter ? this.my_counter : []; 
       let my_array = [name: "static name", counter: my_counter];
       return my_array;
    }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem persists: The variable my_counter is "undefined" at this point. However, when displaing the property, the variable my:counter is properly shown.